# Does gcloud mysql 5.7 support AES-128-CFB8 block encryption mode?

Tags: mysql, encryption, gcloud, google-cloud-sql

Trying to decrypt data using AES-128-CFB8 mode on a gcloud mysql 5.7 instance and getting this error:

> SET block_encryption_mode = 'AES-256-CFB8';

> Error Code: 1231. Variable 'block_encryption_mode' can't be set to the value of 'AES-256-CFB8'

Which make me think that Google SQL Cloud is not supporting this type, although it seems that mysql is compiled with OpenSSL which should support majority of ciphers modes starting with mysql.5.6 according to [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/encryption-functions.html)

Comment: Do you have a local version that does? If so, is there a way of checking the build config?

Answer (score 1):

You're correct. Unfortunately, `block_encryption_mode` is not yet supported in Cloud SQL. It is also currently not included in [supported flags](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/flags#list-flags-mysql).

However, here's a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/62218198) currently available. I highly suggest that you let the engineers know by indicating that you're affected so the thread can be updated and others can see it as well.

Here's what you should expect on a feature request:

> You can also request and vote for new Google Cloud features. Unlike issue reports, we don't immediately triage new feature requests. Instead, we wait for a feature to have a handful of stars and, hopefully, comments from several users about how the feature would be useful. So, when it comes to feature requests, it's especially important to vote for an existing request (if one exists) instead of making a duplicate.